# Why is rsync/scp slow from one server but fast from another?

Tags: ssh, networking, rsync, scp

I have 300 GB of large files located in server A. I am at home trying to copy those files, and both `scp` and `rsync` are painfully slow (80 KB/s or less).

I also have access to another server B. I can copy all my files from server A to server B with `scp` or `rsync` at 20 MB/s.

Finally, I can copy my files from server B to my home with `scp` or `rsync` at 20 MB/s.

Can someone help me understand why this happens (and if I can I fix it). I am a linux/network novice, so I appreciate any help in the right direction.

**Summary:**

```
A ->      Home  (super slow)

A -> B -> Home  (a lot faster)
```

Comment: The minimum MTU may be different along both network paths. If PMTU discovery does not work, that could cause such problems. Can you sucessfully do `ping -s 1472 A ; ping -s 1472 B` with the same number?

Comment: @HaukeLaging (From Home) If I do: `ping -s 1472 A` it just hangs there. But if I do `ping -s 1472 B` it starts printing `1480 bytes from B (XXX.XX.XXX.XXX): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=8.16 ms`.

Answer (score 1):

## MTU

[Path MTU Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery) seems not to be working between you and `A`.

The good solution would be to fix that and there are certainly answers on this site which explain how to do that.

As a simple work-around you can set the MTU for the respective target IP in the routing table both on `A` (more important) and on your system at home.

In order not to waste bandwidth you should determine the maximum reliable MTU for that path. Do that by running

```
ping -s 1472 A
```

with lower numbers. Especially 1464 has a good chance.

Short version: Some (most) of the IP packets are too large and thus get dropped. You must force `A` (and maybe your home system, too, but the packets in that direction may be small enough anyway) to send smaller packets.

## routing table

Your routing table (on both systems) looks something like this:

```
root@vm:~# ip r
default via 192.168.213.3 dev bridgeport 
192.168.213.0/24 dev bridgeport proto kernel scope link src 192.168.213.122
```

With this command

```
ip route add 10.9.8.0/24 via 192.168.213.3 mtu 1480
```

you can add an entry for a host or subnet. You use your default gateway for that entry, too.

The `mtu` setting you use for that is 1500 minus the difference of 1472 and the value you found (let's assume 1464):

- 1472-1464=8
- `A-home` MTU = 1500-8 = 1492
- `ip route add ... mtu 1492`

```
root@vm:~# ip r
default via 192.168.213.3 dev bridgeport 
10.9.8.0/24 via 192.168.213.3 dev bridgeport mtu 1480 
192.168.213.0/24 dev bridgeport proto kernel scope link src 192.168.213.122
```

This is not a permanent setting. It will disappear after a reboot or (probably) network reload. Test again with `ping` after adding this route.